# DNS Forwarder with rename / alias

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I would like to setup (I think) an authoritative DNS server for a subdomain but have it lookup the IP address/es of another name with another DNS server and return it for the subdomain.

Can I use bind. How do I configure it?

A bit more background.

In AWS I have an internal ELB (load balancer).

I have a VPN connected to the AWS network (VPC).

I can access the ELB by IP but the ELB name is not publicly resolvable. It is only resolvable using the internal AWS DNS server.

Unfortunately the AWS DNS server will not respond to requests from outside of the AWS network (VPC).

I have got a BIND server setup inside the AWS network to forward requests to the internal AWS DNS server and can now resolve the ELB name from the network connected through the VPN.

However I want to query for the subdomain name not the name of the ELB (which I can't control).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunatly, don't know about AWS yet but are you just trying to set up bind in order to be the dns of a subdomain? I.e, you don't own `example.com`, but `sub.example.com` and you then want to be able to create `www.sub.example.com` ?

Comment: Sort of. I will actually own both but example.com will be public. sub.example.com will only be resolvable internally (via bind). Forwarding the zone looks straight forward but I want to have sub.example.com actually route to something like elb-123-aws.com where elb-123-aws.com isn't publically resolvable. i.e I need to forward and alias